# Document object by jquery or javascript difference

Tags: javascript, jquery

When We use jQuery, we can use like below

```
var textObj = $("#doc");
textObj.html("Hello");
```

On the other hand, JavaScript can be used like below

```
var textObj = document.getElementById("doc")
textObj.innerHTML = "Hello";
```

But I can't use like below

```
var textObj = $("#doc");
textObj.innerHTML = "Hello";
```

What's main difference these document objects? By jQuery and JavaScript.
I'm asking this because when I try to control table, below code worked.

```
var rows = $("tr");
for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){         
    if((rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML != "") 
      && (rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML == rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML)){
         rows[i].cells[0].className = "winner";
    }
}
```

However, I tried to start from 'table' level, it doesn't work

```
var x = $("#myTable");
for(var i=0;i<x.rows.length;i++){           
    if((x.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML != "") 
       && (x.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML == x.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML)){
...
```

Interestingly, this code works

```
var x = document.getElementById("myTable");

for(var i=0;i<x.rows.length;i++){           
   if((x.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML != "") 
     && (x.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML == x.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML)){
    ...
```

jQuery and JavaScript Document Object don't share properties?

Comment: `$("someselector")` returns a jQuery object which is a wrapper for the zero or more elements that matched the selector you used - like an array of DOM elements (but not an actual array). The jQuery object doesn't have an `.innerHTML` property, instead providing its own methods like `.html()` (which lets you update the html of all the matching elements in one step rather than manually coding your own loop - behind the scenes jQuery uses a loop). Note that the objects returned by plain JS methods like `querySelectorAll()` and `getElementsByClassName()` are also array-like.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a framework on top of javascript. They want you to use their functions to make changes to the DOM.
So if you want to change the 'innerHtml' in jQuery, you use

```
object.html("<br> newline is cool!");
```

http://api.jquery.com/html/

So syntax in jQuery is normaly like object.value("Some value"); object.text("Some text") and so on, while javascript is more like

```
object.innerHtml = "<br> newline is cool!";
```

jQuery wraps all the javascript into nice little functions, so you don't have to think about cross browser support and which functions performs the best.

So when you call something with jQuery, you get an jQuery object back, not the same as what you would get in Javascript.

If you want the javascript DOM element you could do something like:

```
var foo = $( "#foo" )[ 0 ]; // Equivalent to document.getElementById( "foo" )
```

This way you can once again use pure javascript methods.